# Mail server not sending or receiving after removal from barracuda blacklist to white list

Tags: email-server, blacklist, 1and1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mail loops back to myself | postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/69991/mail-loops-back-to-myself-postfix)

Mail server not sending or receiving after removal from barracuda blacklist to white list. I've checked against black lists and the ip and domain are clean. 1and1 are saying its Barracuda black list and barracuda are saying its not blacklisted and that its somethign with 1and1 server.

section from log file...

```
Sep 20 04:29:25 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16906]: connect from mta860.chtah.net[63.236.31.146]
Sep 20 04:29:25 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16070]: connect from host81-136-144-117.in-addr.btopenworld.com[81.136.144.117]
Sep 20 04:29:27 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: raidon - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: 1348111767.185119 LOGOUT, user=mb@mbelectrics.net, ip=[86.143.136.249], top=0, retr=0, time=151, rcvd=18, sent=283, maildir=/var/qmail/mailnames/mbelectrics.net/mb/Maildir
Sep 20 04:29:28 vegaserve pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:28 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[15388]: connect from mta965.emails.itv.com[8.30.201.55]
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18194]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24879]: 95CB31E87556C: message-id=<20120920032929.95CB31E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 95CB31E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=975, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18194]: disconnect from uspmta172097.emarsys.net[195.54.172.97]
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 95CB31E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25897]: warning: 95CB31E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:29 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 95CB31E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:32 vegaserve pop3d: Connection, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:37 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: rei - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:38 vegaserve pop3d: Connection, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:38 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[19328]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18331]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[24464]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24825]: BD1A71E87556C: message-id=<20120920032940.BD1A71E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: BD1A71E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=673, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[24464]: disconnect from unknown[118.97.212.190]
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: BD1A71E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25995]: warning: BD1A71E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:40 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: BD1A71E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:41 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24879]: 0A42B1E87556C: message-id=<20120920032941.0A42B1E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:41 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 0A42B1E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=961, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:41 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18331]: disconnect from bay0-omc4-s10.bay0.hotmail.com[65.54.190.212]
Sep 20 04:29:41 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 0A42B1E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.03/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:41 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25897]: warning: 0A42B1E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:41 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 0A42B1E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[17511]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24825]: 8F8991E87556C: message-id=<20120920032943.8F8991E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 8F8991E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=946, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[17511]: disconnect from blu0-omc4-s22.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.161]
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 8F8991E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.02/0/0.02/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25995]: warning: 8F8991E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 8F8991E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24879]: 088641E87556C: message-id=<20120920032944.088641E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 088641E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=1078, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[19328]: disconnect from smtp10.bis7.eu.blackberry.com[178.239.85.15]
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 088641E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25995]: warning: 088641E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 088641E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: rin - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve pop3d: Connection, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18965]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24825]: 946F51E87556C: message-id=<20120920032944.946F51E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 946F51E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=1173, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18965]: disconnect from hubrelay-rd.bt.com[62.239.224.99]
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 946F51E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25897]: warning: 946F51E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 946F51E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:45 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[14816]: connect from col0-omc2-s12.col0.hotmail.com[65.55.34.86]
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16900]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24879]: 961721E87556C: message-id=<20120920032947.961721E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 961721E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=1082, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16900]: disconnect from mta-35d2.livingsocial.com[199.91.53.210]
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 961721E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25995]: warning: 961721E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:29:47 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 961721E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:29:50 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: rini - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:50 vegaserve pop3d: Connection, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:52 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[24478]: connect from col0-omc2-s13.col0.hotmail.com[65.55.34.87]
Sep 20 04:29:52 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18923]: connect from www.idbwplan.com[193.181.254.21]
Sep 20 04:29:55 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[15968]: connect from 105-48.mta.dotmailer.com[94.143.105.48]
Sep 20 04:29:56 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: ringo - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:29:56 vegaserve pop3d: Connection, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:30:00 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18772]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:30:01 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24825]: 1DAD71E87556C: message-id=<20120920033001.1DAD71E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:30:01 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 1DAD71E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=1022, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:30:01 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18772]: disconnect from mail95.us2.mcsv.net[173.231.139.95]
Sep 20 04:30:01 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 1DAD71E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
Sep 20 04:30:01 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25897]: warning: 1DAD71E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Sep 20 04:30:01 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 1DAD71E87556C: removed
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: ritsuko - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16911]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve pop3d: Connection, ip=[201.80.253.153]
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve postfix/cleanup[24879]: 8AADD1E87556C: message-id=<20120920033002.8AADD1E87556C@vegaserve.com>
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve postfix/qmgr[14378]: 8AADD1E87556C: from=<double-bounce@vegaserve.com>, size=1003, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16911]: disconnect from mr133.createsend.com[184.106.86.133]
Sep 20 04:30:02 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 8AADD1E87556C: to=<postmaster@vegaserve.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
```

Comment: Please post an example of a bounce message, or some error logs, or something that we can actually work with.

Comment: You seem to have a communication error with a before-queue filter: `Sep 20 04:30:00 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[18772]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out`. Update your question with the output of `postconf -n` and the content of your `master.cf`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were probably listed for a valid reason, take a look at:

[Fighting Spam - What can I do as an: Email Administrator, Domain Owner, or User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user)

You can check your status with Barracuda Central using their [lookup tool.](http://www.barracudacentral.org/lookups)

If you *are* listed, you may use their [removal request form](http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've already checked with Barracuda and they removed me yesterday but the mail server is still down and i'm not on any other blacklists.

Comment: Did you double-check whether you are on the blacklist using the tool I linked? You may still be on it... or even worse, you could have triggered a relisting.

Comment: I did and i'm not on the black list

Comment: here's a segment of the log...

Comment: Sep 20 04:29:25 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16906]: connect from mta860.chtah.net[63.236.31.146]
Sep 20 04:29:25 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[16070]: connect from host81-136-144-117.in-addr.btopenworld.com[81.136.144.117]
Sep 20 04:29:27 vegaserve pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [201.80.253.153]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: raidon - short names not allowed from @ [201.80.253.153]ERR: 1348111767.185119 LOGOUT, user=mb@mbelectrics.net, ip=[86.143.136.249], top=0, retr=0, time=151, rcvd=18, sent=283, maildir=/var/qmail/mailnames/mbelectrics.net/mb/Maildir

Comment: @user137765 this is a piece of log mainly showing IMAP login sessions, not SMTP message reception or delivery logs. While IMAP might be part of your problem as well, your initial problem description indicated that message transport is broken - you should post a larger piece of the log by editing your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

> Mail server not sending

this might or might not be a blacklisting problem - you have not provided enough details with your question to give a definitive answer

> or receiving

this however might not. The ability to receive mail would not be impacted by the fact that your server's address is listed on any DNSBL / RBL.

> Sep 20 04:29:43 vegaserve postfix/smtpd[17511]: warning: connect to proxy service 127.0.0.1:10025: Connection timed out

This indicates that you have set up postfix to forward all mail to a before-queue mail filter (probably Amavisd-New) listening on 127.0.0.1 port 10025. However, nothing is answering at 127.0.0.1:10025, probably because Amavis is not started. The SMTP dialog with the original mail client is probably aborted as the result.

> Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/smtp[25748]: 946F51E87556C: to=, orig_to=, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for vegaserve.com loops back to myself)
>
> Sep 20 04:29:44 vegaserve postfix/bounce[25897]: warning: 946F51E87556C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded

A postmaster notification to `postmaster@vegaserve.com` is generated (probably to inform you that your filter is not working), `vegaserve.com`'s MX record is pointing to your postfix server, but is apparently not set up as a *"local"* (i.e. final) destination there - either directly as a list element to the [`mydestination` configuration directive](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) or in one of the hash files referenced by it. In this case, the mail is routed out, but comes back to postfix where it again is intended to be routed out - a mail loop detected and logged by postfix.

Comment: how would i go about checking the configuration?

Comment: would anyone be willing to fix this for me and offer their rates?
I'm in over my head

Comment: @user137765 edited answer - check it out