# X-Postfix; Mailboxes not found when mail comes from others servers

Tags: postfix, configuration, email-server

I had installed and configured dovecot, postfix, and postfixadmin step by step from [this tutorial](http://www.campworld.net/thewiki/pmwiki.php/LinuxServersCentOS/Cent6VirtMailServer) on my server (CentOS6).

I can create virtual mailboxes as well now and can login to roundcubemail, I can also send emails but when I want to send email from other mail systems like gmail, yahoo and etc then I get this error:

> This is the mail system at host domain.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
>   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
>   delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>
> The mail system
>
> ```
> <admin@domain.com>: unknown user: "admin"
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; admin@domain.com
> Original-Recipient: rfc822;admin@domain.com
> Action: failed
> Status: 5.1.1
> Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "admin"
> ```

This is postfix `main.cf`:

```
# network settings
inet_interfaces = all
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf
```

And the `mynetworks` file:

```
192.168.0.0/16
10.0.0.0/8
127.0.0.0/8
[::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
[::1]/128
127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
130.185.0.0/16 # -> my domain ip
```

And `mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf`:

```
hosts = localhost
user = postfix
password = postfixpassword
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' and backupmx = '1'
```

The error showing up in the logs is the following:

```
postfix/local[19002]: 38902E0550: to=<admin@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.09, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "admin")
```

After reading some posts and I changed mydestination from this

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
```

to

```
mydestination = localhost
```

but after this change, I the error in the logs change to:

```
postfix/smtp[18844]: D6EEFE0550: to=<admin@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.14, delays=0.05/0.01/0.08/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for domain.com loops back to myself)
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add delivery log (i.e. log when postfix reject email) in both conditions, before and after you change `mydestination` parameter

Comment: log added, please read it

Comment: I doubt you read all the [previous questions containing this error](http://serverfault.com/search?q=[postfix]+mail+for+loops+back+to+myself). I guess from these, that the log is from the `mydestination = localhost` setting, which is apparently false for a public mailserver. To cite from [another answer](http://serverfault.com/a/70005/217116): _This happens when domain.com has an MX record (or, in the absence of an MX, an A record) that points to your Postfix server, but your Postfix server is not configured to accept mail for that domain._

Comment: I did every change but none of them helped me till now, maybe some things is wrong here :(

Comment: Please describe the changes you made and your problems **in detail**, not, _simle things are wrong_!
You did change `relay_domains`, which is by default `$mydestination`, that lists the domains that are deliverd locally. You have to insert your domains into the MySQL table there, have you done that?

Comment: if `myhostname = domain.com` and `mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost` then error is `www postfix/local[19002]: 38902E0550: to=<admin@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.09, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "admin")` and if `myhostname = mail.domain.com` and `mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost` then error is `www postfix/smtp[18844]: D6EEFE0550: to=<admin@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.14, delays=0.05/0.01/0.08/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for domain.com loops back to myself)`

Comment: I added domain.com and mail.domain.com to my TABLE database and alises mail.domain.com to domain.com from postfixadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Changed `host.domain.com` to `server.domain.com` and problem solved, because `mail.domain.com` was as MX record in my DNS settings

Comment: -.- So, you could have (very!) easily solved this problem yourself, by searching for the error message in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, firstly I would backup `mail.log` then reverted all changes to the state from the tutorial, then I would add to main.cf:

```
debug_peer_level = 5
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
```

then blanked mail.log `cat /dev/null > /var/log/mail.log` restarted postfix and manually connect to postfix (here is only the commands I would input):

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
ehlo 127.0.0.1
mail from: <my_email_at@gmail.com>
rcpt to: <admin@domain.com>
quit
```

then stopped postfix and analyze the logs. Searched for `>>> CHECKING RECIPIENT MAPS <<<` and looked below fir any errors.

One more question: only admin isn't working or any address ?

Comment: I do this, and got some log, but can not post here, because I have not enough space for it, but you can see in this link: [error log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7794121/) and for your Q, all of the address do not work

Comment: This is interesting cause line 44 of that logs (`Jul 14 20:11:36 domain postfix/smtpd[9206]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 250 2.1.5 Ok`) says that the lookup was successful so postfix found that user. I think that there is some logic error in the configuration. I would suggest go through config line by line. Gonna try setup using that tutorial, later today....